# Less than 6 months on Philippine Passport travelling to Toulouse, France

Tags: transit

With only 5 months of validity on my passport, will Airliners and Immigration stop me from travelling to Toulouse, France. I'm coming from Manila and will be passing through/transiting at Hong Kong & Heathrow.

Comment: Have you applied for a visa yet?  I imagine if your intended travel dates and your passport validity conflict the embassy would not issue the visa or at least draw your attention to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Tom is correct in pointing out that your concern should be the visa application rather than the airline or immigration officers.  The requirement is that your passport be valid for at least three months after your anticipated departure.  If your passport validity is insufficient for your planned travel, you should get a new passport before making your visa application.

Source: [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018), article 12.